# Where to look up GCC's implementation of implementation-defined behavior?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, bit-fields

As the C++ standard is very vague on many things, I want to look up the concrete implementations from different compilers. At the moment, I want to know how GCC allocates and aligns bit fields.

In the case of the MS Visual C++ compiler, it is very easy: There is a [nice page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx) in the user manual about bit fields which explains all open allocation/alignment questions, and there are even figures and examples.

I just want the same information for GCC, but it seems to be way more complicated. There is a [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) in the GCC manual which just states "Determined by ABI." Then we have some information about [ABI policy and guidelines](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) which contains a link to a document named [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) on Github. Now, in this document, we can found the following: "the bitfield is allocated as required by the underlying C psABI". And that's the point were I'm stuck. I can find no helpful sites when searching for C psABI.

Can anyone please point me to the site where GCC's implementation of bit fields is described? It can't be that complicated, can't it? Why is GCC's documentation so often so much more complicated then Microsoft's? Am I using the wrong resources?

Comment: How about [this](http://www.uclibc.org/specs.html) for a list of psABIs

Comment: Are you really using an itanium?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks, I must have overlooked this.

Comment: @NateEldredge the Itanian ABI is widely used on non-Itanium hardware.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, I'm not using Itanium. I found this strange, too. But the linked manual page seems to direct me straight to this Itanium document...

Comment: @user1494080 it looks like you will need to refer to the x86 documentation on bit fields though since as far as I can tell the Itanium psABI points back to it since it says `Alignment for memebrs of aggregates match existing Ia-32 conventions`.

Comment: @user1494080 Keep in mind that gcc supports dozens of hardware/OS combinations while MS supports...one or two?

Comment: Half of the questions in the last paragraph are rethorical and opinionated. You might want to remove those. BTW, you often find the documentation you use the most simpler and easier. I would love to find a document describing Microsoft´s C++ ABI for x86/x64... I don't find Itanium C++ ABI to be an easy read, but at least it is available

Comment: Why should I remove them? I already got some useful answers to them. I asked myself indeed why the documentation is that complicated. And I don't think that this is a subjective opinion. When you are referred from one document to another to another... then this is definitively complicated. But, well, as the answers say, it maybe have to be that complicated, as due to the variety of different platforms, there is one single answer how GCC, to come back to the original question, aligns and allocates bit fields. So I stand behind all my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the difference between GCC (which runs on many, many different machines and operating systems, each with their own convention on how to do some things, the platform's ABI) and MS C, which runs on one platform only (essentially). But that is not all, there are other areas where the standard doesn't dictate what to do, in order to give the compiler writer leeway. If the platform doen't mandate anything either, the compiler writer can choose at will. And the selection might even change seemingly at random from one version of the compiler to the next on the same platform. The compiler should document its choices, but for a beast like GCC covering so many platforms it can be a daunting task to find that.

Comment: The answer to my concrete question was already given in the comments, but thanks for elaborating a bit on the more "general/philosophical" questions. I can now understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

G++ documents this in §4.9 of its manual.  On the other hand,
the documentation isn't really very helpful, since it says that
it is "determined by ABI"; in other words, g++ will do whatever
the binary ABI of the platform requires.  Thus, under Windows,
it will do exactly what Visual C++ would do, under Solaris what
Sun CC would do, and under Linux, what g++ would do.  And if the
latter is somewhat circular...  The ABI for C is normally
defined by the system, and not the compiler; the compiler just
conforms.  And I don't know where to find this information for
Linux.  (Differences in the ABI on the same processor have
created so many problems in the past that some chip
manufacturers have defined an ABI from the start.  This tends to
only apply to recent architectures.)

As for GCC's documentation being more complicated than
Microsoft's, I've not found that.  Neither are particularly
complete, often leaving some of the most important issues, like
threading, unspecified.

Comment: Shouldn't the x86 psABI be valid for Linux, too?

Comment: Linux on x86 conforms to the System V ABI, if I recall correctly, and for x86-64 there's an ABI written by AMD.